# Magento CMS Page keep redirect to homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, cms-pages

I don't know why my CMS page content keep automatically redirect to homepage.

Example: I click on link below:

http://magento.lifegood.com.my/customer-service

then my magento site will bring me to homepage.

I totally have no idea to fix this bug after I hard trying one day on it.

**Update:** Here is my [.htaccess](http://magento.lifegood.com.my/htaccess.txt)

Comment: add your .htaccess code here

Comment: @PrashantValanda here is my .htaccess - http://magento.lifegood.com.my/htaccess.txt

Answer (score 6):

```
Open your admin panel of magento.

Goto

System>Configuration>>Web> URL Option

and change

Auto-redirect to Base URL to No.
```

Comment: Thank you assist, I had changed my setting but still get the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

As I see - all your cms pages redirects to home page.
This can mean that CMS Magento module is broken or disabled.

1) Check "Admin - System - Configuration - Advanced" and find Mage_Cms line there. Check if it's not disabled.

2) Go to "Admin - System - Configuration - Developer" and enable Logging 
Then click on Cms page link on frontend
And then check var/log/ folder of your Magento instance. Some info can appear there

Answer (score 0):

One another thing that you need to remember is if you're site is accessed on https like

https://www.yourdomain.com/

> You should also make sure that the base Link URL should be on https
>   too. Otherwise Magento .htaccess rules will redirect you back to the
>   Base Url

So the bottom line is  **URL Base Link** under system - configuration - web - HTTP should be https://www.yourdomain.com/

After this clean / refresh your cache and reload your pages, This time magento wont reidrect you to home page.

> web/unsecure/base_link_url

If you dont want to do this, then you need to change the .htaccess rules as shown in this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/25528651/777103